# Intent to modify INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS setting

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have an app that should self-update for this I need `INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS` to be enabled, so I guide the user to a settings page to enable this option.

Problem is that this option seems to be in different places on different devices, can someone tell me how I can determine where this setting is located programmatically depending on device, carrier, API level, or whatever?

This is what I currently have:

```
static public void startActivityToEnableUnknownSources(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: what results u are getting when running this code?

Comment: It takes the user to the security settings page.

Comment: for which android version u have this application?

Comment: `minSdk` is 7, `targetSdk` is 17

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11649591/932307) and I quote from @commonsware

Device manufacturers are welcome to change the organization of items in Settings, and there is little we can do about it. You are welcome to crowd-source a database of devices and where the locations of key settings (like "Unknown sources") reside, then use that database to help drive your app's behavior, defaulting to ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS for those that are not in the database. Beyond that, though, there is little we can do.